I am looking for a WebHID scale that has a precision of .01 oz
I am working on a WebHID project and am using the Dymo scales. Unfortunately, the Dymo scale only have a precision to .1 oz and I need .01 oz. Does anyone know of any other scales that are WebHID and have precision to the .01 oz. Thanks!
I have been looking and can't seem to find one. There doesn't seem to be a lot of WebHid supported scales out there.

You don't need a scale that supports "WebHID", any scale that advertises support for HID should work with WebHID API. You could also use a serial scale with Web Serial API.
Try searching for "list of HID scales" to find more compatible devices.
